# PHP While Loop + passing value

Tags: php, loops

At the start, I let variable timerow=1. Then I while loop my program 5 times. Every time it loops, it creates a form that is to be submitted to `test2.php` with the value of variable timerow.

So, when I clicked on the value 4, I expect the value 4 to be displayed at test2.php.

However, the value at test2.php always turns out to be 1. Please assist!

At test.php

```
<?php
$timerow=1;
$x=1;
while($x <= 5){
echo "<form id=\"timeslot\" action=\"test2.php\" method=\"POST\">";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"timely\" value=\""; echo $timerow; echo "\"/>";
echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('timeslot').submit();\">"; echo $timerow; echo "</a>";
echo "</form>";
$x++;
$timerow++;
}
?>
```

At test2.php

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' ); 
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false ); 
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' ); 
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$time=$_POST['timely'];
echo $time;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just curious, why make a link with a script to submit a form? You can style a submit button to look like a link if you want.

Comment: You repeat `<form id="timeslot" ...` five times. So only the first form will ever be submitted.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see, what an amateur mistake by me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the forms is given the same id. That doesn't work, because an id is unique within the document. The first form 'claims' it, and the other forms effectively don't get an id at all.

Since you use (or abuse) a link with a script to submit the form, which gets the form by its id, each of the submit links effectively submits the same form.

You can fix this either,

1. by giving each form a unique id (for instance by appending `$timerow` to the id) and using that generated id in the script.
2. by using a normal submit button. This will submit the form it is in, without any script or any need for an id. You can style the button using CSS to mimic a link, if you like. I think this is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

As friends said, when you create multiple HTML elements with the same ID, so you'll get only the first element when you'll try to call that ID.

You can do like this for your given example:

```html
<?php
$timerow=1;
$x=1;
  
while($x <= 5){
  echo "<form id=\"timeslot" . $timerow . "\" action=\"test2.php\" method=\"POST\">";
  echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"timely\" value=\"". $timerow . "\"/>";
  echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"#\"  onclick=\"document.getElementById('timeslot" . $timerow . "').submit();\">" . $timerow . "</a>";
echo "</form>";
  $x++;
  $timerow++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your `test.php` file, You are assigning same id `timeslot` to each form try to send unique id like below:

**test.php**

```
  <?php
    $timerow=1;
    $x=1;
    while($x <= 5){
    echo "<form id=\"timeslot$x\" action=\"test2.php\" method=\"POST\">";
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"timely\" value=\""; echo $timerow; echo "\"/>";
    echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"document.getElementById('timeslot$x').submit();\">"; echo $timerow; echo "</a>";
    echo "</form>";
    $x++;
    $timerow++;
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping the form with id="timeslot", so in all submit actions it always gets the first form. IDs should be unique in an HTMl document.

Try something like this:

```
<?php
 $x=1;
 while($x <= 5){
   echo "<form action=\"test2.php\" method=\"POST\">";
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"timely\" value=\""; echo $x; echo "\"/>";
   echo "<a style=\"text-decoration:none\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"this.parentElement.submit();\">"; echo $x; echo "</a>";
   echo "</form>";
   $x++;
 }
?>
```